# Linux LiveCD Server with FTP & SSH Services

Tags: ssh, ftp, livecd

Could anyone please suggest me a LiveCD (Linux Based) with SSH & FTP Services. Basically I don't want to install anything on my laptop so I just want to boot LiveCD with FTP/SSH services so I can connect from other clients to it and do a FTP/SCP to/from it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you are looking for

- small use damn small linux http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/
- password recovery etc.. backtrack
- full feature get ubuntu

if you want to save time for downloading the image and writing it to a usb stick, be sure to try out [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

They have a lot of live linux image.

If you've got some spare time you can build your own live linux image